# How to get just one number and not two before dot with regex?

Tags: regex

I am trying to get the number `1.039,08180600` with regex but there is numbers like `15.623,77056789`  in the string.

I used `([0-9]?)(\.?)([0-9]{3},[0-9]{8})` to get the `x.xxx,xxxxxxxx`.

Is there a way to do it? And is there a better way to write the regex I am using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A general pattern which might work for you is:

```regex
\b\d\.\d+,\d+\b
```

Comment: In your case it still get the `xx.xxx,xxxxxxxx` as a result. But I tried `\b\d{1}\.\d+,\d+\b` and it works

Comment: You don't need the `{1}`, just use: `\b\d\.\d+,\d+\b`

Answer (score 0):

use `\b` or word boundary, the regex `\b\d\.\d{3},\d{8}\b`

```js
var number = '1.039,08180600 15.623,77056789 2.039,08100 7.039,08180677'
console.log(number.match(/\b\d\.\d{3},\d{8}\b/g))
```